# select first row/transaction based on 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to return the first row for each person on each day and for each panel. I also need a count by panel.

Sample data

```
 evnt_dat, evnt_descrp, panel_descrp, lname, fname, cardno
 10/2/2013 8:30 AM  Local Grant Austin Panel    Evans   Michael 52836                           
 10/2/2013 8:53 AM  Local Grant Austin Panel    Lang    Richard 50385                           
 10/2/2013 8:59 AM  Local Grant Austin Panel    Evans   Michael 52836                                                   
 10/2/2013 9:22 AM  Local Grant Austin Panel    Brozek  Kerry   50346                           
 10/2/2013 9:34 AM  Local Grant Austin Panel    Brozek  Kerry   50346                           
 10/2/2013 10:02 AM Local Grant Austin Panel    Evans   Michael 52836                           
 10/3/2013 7:13 AM  Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Goins   Joseph  21082                           
 10/3/2013 7:13 AM  Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Goins   Joseph  21082                           
 10/3/2013 7:19 AM  Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Bartolovic  Doug    44974                           
 10/3/2013 7:23 AM  Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Bartolovic  Doug    44974
```

desired result:

```
10/2/2013 8:30 AM   Local Grant Austin Panel    Evans   Michael   52836  
10/2/2013 8:53 AM   Local Grant Austin Panel    Lang    Richard 50385     
10/2/2013 9:22 AM   Local Grant Austin Panel    Brozek  Kerry   50346  
count = 3  
10/3/2013 7:13 AM   Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Goins   Joseph  21082  
10/3/2013 7:19 AM   Local Grant Bellevue Panel  Bartolovic  Doug    44974  
count = 2
```

I tried

```sql
;WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cardno ORDER BY convert(date,evnt_dat) DESC) AS RN 
    FROM ev_log ) 
SELECT cardno, lName, fname, evnt_Dat, panel_descrp 
  FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give us by the way a sample output. Because you could not mix the result of count with a detail records.

Comment: Money bounties button needed

Comment: i indicated what the results of the query should be.  one thing I tried is;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cardno 
                       ORDER BY convert(date,evnt_dat) DESC) AS RN
   FROM ev_log
)
SELECT cardno, lName, fname, evnt_Dat, panel_descrp
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1

Comment: It looks like you are trying to group your results. Please read about aggregate functions (MIN in your case for the evnt_dat, and COUNT for the count) and GROUP BY clause

Comment: Please use "Update Question" button and post your SQL statement there. Please also indicate using the tags what RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, evnt_dat)) evnt_dat, 
       evnt_descrp, panel_descrp, lname, fname, cardno
  FROM
(
  SELECT evnt_dat, evnt_descrp, panel_descrp, lname, fname, cardno,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY evnt_descrp, panel_descrp, lname, fname, 
                            DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, evnt_dat)) ORDER BY evnt_dat) rnum
    FROM ev_log
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
 ORDER BY evnt_dat, evnt_descrp, panel_descrp, lname, fname;
```

**Note:** *obviously you can use a CTE instead of an inner select if you like it better*

Sample output:

```
|   EVNT_DAT | EVNT_DESCRP |   PANEL_DESCRP |      LNAME |   FNAME | CARDNO |
|------------|-------------|----------------|------------|---------|--------|
| 2013-10-02 | Local Grant |   Austin Panel |     Brozek |   Kerry |  50346 |
| 2013-10-02 | Local Grant |   Austin Panel |      Evans | Michael |  52836 |
| 2013-10-02 | Local Grant |   Austin Panel |       Lang | Richard |  50385 |
| 2013-10-03 | Local Grant | Bellevue Panel | Bartolovic |    Doug |  44974 |
| 2013-10-03 | Local Grant | Bellevue Panel |      Goins |  Joseph |  21082 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7c3a/10)** demo

Comment: thanks peterm, your first suggestion provides the proper results.

Comment: is there a way to return only the date portion of the evnt_dat column?

Comment: @user2967024 Of course there is. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: thanks again peterm, i was trying this but didn't realize I needed to leave evnt_dat outside the parenthesis also.  obviously a rookie here.

Comment: I need to pull data from another table and the below works independently, I just can figure out how to use it with the existing query.                                                                                                                             select ev_log.evnt_Dat, ev_log.cardno, ev_log.lname, ev_log.panel_descrp,  badge_v.badge_city, badge_v.badge_email
  from badge_c
    join badge_v 
        on badge_v.id = badge_c.id
    join ev_log
        on ev_log.cardno = badge_c.cardno